# How to save data only when data is present in the form?

Tags: jquery

I have this code where I am trying to save data every 5 seconds, only there is data in the form. But when the page loads, the "Form Saved" message appears after an interval of 5 seconds. And it does not appear after that at all, whether data is present in form or not

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(":input").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() !== "") 
                window.setInterval(saveData, 5000);
        }); 
    });

    function saveData(){
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "SaveDraft.aspx",
           data: {
               name: $('#frmTaxSheet').serialize()
           },
           cache: false,
           error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
               alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
           },
           success: function(response) {
                $('#notify').text("Form Data Saved").fadeOut(2000, function() { 
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            ;}
       });
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: make sure the function `saveDraft` or `saveData`?? or `saveDraft` is another function??

Comment: This is something that got changed when I was manually editing the code when I asking the question. I just noticed it and corrected. It was a copy-paste error. The issue still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(saveDraft, 5000);
});

function saveData(){
    var askAjax = true;
    $(":input").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === "") { askAjax &= false; }
    });

    if(askAjax) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "SaveDraft.aspx",
            data: {
                name: $('#frmTaxSheet').serialize()
            },
            cache: false,
            error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                window.setTimeout(saveDraft, 5000);
                $('#notify').text("Form Data Saved").fadeIn(2000, function() {
                    $('#notify').delay('1000').fadeOut(500);
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(saveDraft, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey czerasz, you code is doing the same thing as my code. Also please take into account that form field data must exist to even save.

Comment: You need to adopt it to Your case. In my example the #notify element fadesin in 2s, then it stays for 1s, and disappears in .5s. The saveData function is called almost every 5s. It depends how long the ajax call takes.

Answer (score 1):

try to modify this part:

```
success: function(response) {
            $('#notify').text("Form Data Saved")
                        .css('opacity', '0.5')
                        .animate({'opacity':'1'}, 'slow')
                        .animate({'opacity':'0'}, 'slow');
            });
```

because in :

```
$('#notify').text("Form Data Saved").fadeOut(2000, function() { 
                $(this).remove();
```

you already removed the id `#notify` and on the second `interval request` it is not found in the body

Comment: jogesh_p, it is continuously animating with no end. What I would need is just to flash the message when there is some data.

Comment: @KishorNanda i think because your request is with in 5Sec. and in animate it takes more then 5Sec. Try to replace `fast` instead of 'slow' or manually amount of duration..

Answer (score 1):

What about binding to the keypress event?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("form").on('keypress', function() {
     window.setTimeout(function(){
       saveData();
      }, 5000);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that your code has some quite big misstakes and you should try something like this instead :)

note: If you use :input instead of :text make sure you don't have any hidden fields that will cause your code to break.

note2: Checking if val() != "" will make the ajax to post even if nothing has changed since last post, so detecting onkeypress on :text might be a better solution.

note3: As slightly discussed in earlier answer you might get problem if the ajax + animation takes more than 5 seconds, so a better approach might be to use setTimeout instead of setIntervall and set a new timeout when the ajax and animation is finished.

```
$(function()
{
  window.setInterval(function()
  {
    if($(":text").filter(function(index) { return $(this).val().trim() != ""; }).length > 0)
    {                     
       saveData();
    }
  }, 5000);
});
```